# Disable textbox when checkbox checked in same cell gridview in edit mode on client side

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have problem with disabling textbox on checkbox checked in edittemplate of gridview
Here is the code:

```
     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Navigation Path">
                      <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkNavPath" runat="server" Enabled="false" />
                            <asp:Label ID="lblNavPath" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("NavPath") %>' />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                         <EditItemTemplate>
                           <asp:CheckBox ID="chkEditNavPath" runat="server" Text="Open same image on click?" onclick="GetCheckStatus(this);"  Enabled="true" />
                           <asp:TextBox ID="txtEditNavPath" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("NavPath") %>'></asp:TextBox>

                         </EditItemTemplate>

                      <FooterTemplate>
                                 <asp:CheckBox ID="chkNewNavPath" runat="server" Text="Open same image on click?" Enabled="true" />
                           <asp:TextBox ID="txtNewNavPath" runat="server" Text=""></asp:TextBox>       
                     </FooterTemplate>
                     </asp:TemplateField>
```

The Javascript:

```
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function GetCheckStatus(obj) {
        var GridViewP = document.getElementById('<%=GridViewPDF.ClientID %>')
        debugger;
        if (GridViewP.rows[obj.parentElement.parentElement.rowIndex].cells[4].childNodes[0].type == "checkbox") {
            if (GridViewP.rows[obj.parentElement.parentElement.rowIndex].cells[4].childNodes[0].checked) {
                GridViewP.rows[obj.parentElement.parentElement.rowIndex].cells[4].childNodes[1].enabled = false; // Enable your control here
            }
        }
    }
    </script>
```

I am not able to reach js code, bit newbie I am.

Comment: do you want to do it in javascript?

Comment: @ Felipe Oriani yes .

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown thanks for editting question

Comment: @user3069746 you're welcome dude. What FelipeOriani is saying is that using JavaScript for that is the hard way. You should try to achieve that on the code behind.

Comment: Despite knowing that it could be easily achieved on postback, I required not to post back but to achieve it on client side.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown To achieve the result, I searched google and Stackoverflow whole night but I didn't find solution for edittemplate

Comment: @IrshadAlam did the function is called or the debugger reaches the `debugger` break-point?

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown I have put debugger break-point to see whether the script is reached or not, the function GetCheckStatus() is called onclick event of checkbox. Is that the expected answer ? or u wanted to ask some other thing?

Comment: @IrshadAlam yes. I'm asking that because you have first check if function is called then tray find your desired element. This is the obvious test flow.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown, question is solved, I needed nothing but an appropriate js code. Thanks to you and all who helped me. I have marked the answer below as correct answer, pls check.

Comment: @IrshadAlam Nice! I would like to help more, but I was out of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use following java script code to do that client side
Replace you GetCheckStatus function with following

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function GetCheckStatus(obj) {
if (obj.checked) {
    obj.nextSibling.nextSibling.disabled = true;
}
else {
    obj.nextSibling.nextSibling.disabled = false;
}      
}
</script>
```

You have to call this function with onchange event instead onclick of checkbox like following

```
onchange="GetCheckStatus(this);"
```

**EDIT :**

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function GetCheckStatus(obj) {
     if (obj.childNodes[0].checked) {
        obj.nextSibling.nextSibling.disabled = true;
     }
     else {
        obj.nextSibling.nextSibling.disabled = false;
     }      
    }
</script>
```

Apply function with onchange event

Comment: I put it, not working. Pls check asp code of mine, have I written it correctly to call js function?

Comment: you have to use onchange instead of onclick

Comment: Applied your edit, but I am sorry, not working. May I inform you that this row is in editing mode.

Comment: Thanks Jignesh, it worked. I couldn't vote it up, coz I don't have 15 points, but you helped me a lot.